# Zorin OS 11 Lite, No Sound Driver

Tags: audio

### Hello!

I have an problem with Zorin OS 11 Lite, Fresh installation, and i can hear sound only with my Headphones!
[An Screenshot Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlVPN.png)

Alsa, Installed.
PulseAudio, Installed.

```
kubanezi@AHG-CREW:~$ aplay -l | grep card
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH5]
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH5 - IEC958]
kubanezi@AHG-CREW:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH5]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH5 [Intel ICH5], device 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH5 - IEC958]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
kubanezi@AHG-CREW:~$
```

I have try to re'install alsa+pulseaudio re'start and to reboot my pc but is not working :/ 
Any idea how can i fix this?!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the history?  Is this something that was previously working and suddenly stopped?  You say it's a new installation of the OS.  Did it work with the previous OS?  What was that?  What kind of computer?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes sound work in first time (after installation of Zorin) 
but volume was like 5% 
Just i try to restart Alsa and after this has not work anymore!
Before has ben windows XP and sound has work good!